# Подключение плагина Go к Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, golang

Скачала, установила плагин, как и полагается. Однако go-проект нормально создать не получилось. В чём может быть проблема?
Может необходимо прописать GOROOT и GOPATH в IDEA?

[image: Скрин:]

Comment: Что значит _проект нормально создать не получилось_?

Comment: GOROOT лучше вообще не трогать. GOPATH должен быть прописан как переменная окружения. Присоединяюсь к Regent, что именно идёт не так?

Comment: Всё, разобралась. Надо было ручками src создать и main-файл. А я думала, что идея сама может это сделать.
Кстати, по поводу GOPATH и GOROOT. Для среды LiteIDE GOPATH нужно прописывать в etc/environment или bashrc?

Comment: Я ставлю в bashrc. Главное чтобы она была экспортирована и компилятор её видел.

Comment: @MilenaMansurova  Пожалуйста, задавайте новые вопросы в новой теме, а не в комментариях к старой.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434901/#comment452692_434901):

Надо было «ручками» *src* создать и *main*-файл.